# Column displaynames are not translated

Tags: 2010

I have one site collection with 20 subsites.
One root content type which fields displaynames are translated with resource files.
On the subsites there are lists that use that content type.

19 sites, when I click on the new form, shows the correct translation of the fields, the 20th does not.

What can I check??

oddd

Comment: Use ULS viewer to see whats going behind the scenes :)

Comment: It's not working for me :( For example the column names of my default "Tasks list" do not get updated. I tried to update the columns and views using the a following code: using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://test.local")) { for (int l = site.AllWebs.Count - 1; l >= 0; l--) { using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[l]) { //foreach (SPList list in web.Lists) for (int j = web.Lists.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--) { SPList list = web.Lists[j]; for (int i = list.Fields.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { SPField field = list.Fields[i]; field.Update(); Debug.WriteLine(web.Name + " - " + list.Title + " - " + field.Internal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is weird.

the solution was:
with powershell, get all list columns and do an update on spfield, then suddenly the fields are translated. lol microsoft!